# I want to add a fuction in String object prototype to check it is valid or not

Tags: javascript

like here we have string and validate is a function that i want to add in a String prototye and validate fuction accept the condtition string argument and i want to parse the condtion and return the true or false on the basis of the validate condition of the string.

```
'any-string-2'.validate('!empty')

'any-string-3'.validate('length>30')

'any-string-4'.validate('!length<=10')

'any-string-5'.validate('length=3')

'any-string-6'.validate(/^.*-s/i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest this to the best of my understanding of your question:

here Str is the class object on which you want to call the validate function

```
Str.prototype.validate= function(criteria) {
  // process the object based on your criteria condition and return the same 
};
```

Comment: yes. but how i can parse the string condtion which is inside the validate fuction in a form of string. 'any-string-5'.validate('length=3') this validate fuction takes a condtion in string format which is 'length=3' then how i can check this condition.

Comment: Brute force: use conditional statements based on criteria string and return the same